# How do i make a list from Django queryset and format the annotate field?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to make my django query json serializable

```
queryset= list(Products.objects.filter(status=True, salelog__created__range=(start,today)).values("name").annotate(individual_sales=Count("salelog__quantity")).annotate(combined_quantity=Sum("salelog__quantity")))
```

so i return json_response(queryset)

and i get the following for combined_quantity: *null*

but when i print(queryset) in terminal i get the following:

```
[{'name': 'STEAK', 'individual_sales': 21, 'combined_quantity': Decimal('300.00')},
 {'name': 'RIBEYE', 'individual_sales': 18, 'combined_quantity': Decimal('500.00')},
 {'name': 'T-BONE', 'individual_sales': 8, 'combined_quantity': Decimal('450.00')}]
```

i guess the Decimal(xxx) doesnt play well with my front end.
how do i fix this?

btw im using vue and django and  pretty new at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DJango has a built in JSON encoder that handles things like decimals and dates.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/serialization/#djangojsonencoder

In your question, I note that you are using json_response.  I'm not sure what that is, but using [Django's JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) should use the djangojsonencoder.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
...
return JsonResponse(queryset, safe=False)
#use safe is false as you have a list of dicts, not just a dict.
```